# Azure Logic App - Idling before starting execution?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

One of our Azure Logic Apps is experiencing a bizarre gap in timing from time of invocation to the time it actually begins executing.  This is resulting in extremely long and erroneous run lengths.  Here is an example of a problematic run:

```
Start date: Friday, December 13, 2019, 1:45:42 PM
End date: Friday, December 13, 2019, 2:24:30 PM
```

**Run Duration: 38.79 minutes**

```
Check_if_journal_file   0 Milliseconds
Condition   0 Milliseconds
Delay   1.52 Seconds
Get_Blob_Metadata   15 Milliseconds
HTTP    281 Milliseconds
ImportBreakpointJournalFile 406 Milliseconds
Initialize_JobHttpStatusCode    110 Milliseconds
Journal_file_failed_to_process  0 Milliseconds
Journal_file_successfully_processed 31 Milliseconds
Not_a_journal_file  0 Milliseconds
Set_variable    157 Milliseconds
Until   4.69 Seconds
```

**Actual Action Execution Duration: 7.21 seconds**

[Action Execution Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qYOp.jpg)

Since the execution itself only took ~7 seconds, that means the logic app was just sitting there idling doing nothing for almost 38 minutes!  Runs previous to this one show no timing problems.

Has anyone else seen behavior like this?

What would cause a logic app to idle for 38 minutes before beginning execution?

**UPDATE:**

Turned on detailed diagnostics for the logic app and got the following results which show that it really is idling or suspended.  You can see that job 08586252374669322278104928528CU37 begins at 12:23 then almost immediately suspends? before taking **any action** and then resumes at 12:58 for no apparent reason.  After resuming you can see it begins executing normally as Initialize_JobHttpStatusCode is the first action in the app.

```
TimeGenerated [UTC]         startTime_t [UTC]           waitEndTime_t [UTC]         resource_runId_s                    resource_originRunId_s              resource_actionName_s           endTime_t [UTC]

12/15/2019, 12:58:57.627 AM 12/15/2019, 12:58:57.471 AM Invalid Date                08586252374669322278104928528CU37                                       Initialize_JobHttpStatusCode    12/15/2019, 12:58:57.549 AM
12/15/2019, 12:58:57.540 AM 12/15/2019, 12:58:57.471 AM Invalid Date                08586252374669322278104928528CU37                                       Initialize_JobHttpStatusCode    Invalid Date
12/15/2019, 12:58:57.405 AM 12/15/2019, 12:23:38.550 AM 12/15/2019, 12:58:57.330 AM 08586252374669322278104928528CU37   08586252374669322278104928528CU37                                   Invalid Date
12/15/2019, 12:58:57.282 AM 12/15/2019, 12:58:56.901 AM Invalid Date                08586252353485738359883907091CU99                                                                       12/15/2019, 12:58:56.980 AM
12/15/2019, 12:58:57.258 AM 12/15/2019, 12:58:56.901 AM Invalid Date                08586252353485738359883907091CU99                                                                       Invalid Date
12/15/2019, 12:58:57.247 AM 12/15/2019, 12:58:56.909 AM Invalid Date                08586252353485738359883907091CU99   08586252353485738359883907091CU99                                   Invalid Date
12/15/2019, 12:23:39.275 AM 12/15/2019, 12:23:38.534 AM Invalid Date                08586252374669322278104928528CU37                                                                       12/15/2019, 12:23:39.034 AM
12/15/2019, 12:23:39.172 AM 12/15/2019, 12:23:38.534 AM Invalid Date                08586252374669322278104928528CU37                                                                       Invalid Date
12/15/2019, 12:23:39.143 AM 12/15/2019, 12:23:38.550 AM Invalid Date                08586252374669322278104928528CU37   08586252374669322278104928528CU37                                   Invalid Date
```

[Logic App Suspend? Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHrXI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps will not be idle once its triggered. In your case, the Logic App would have retried few action for certain period. The retry policy is configurable upto 1 day. You can inspect and check the Logic App run if it has under gone some retries.

Comment: The one task does retry but you can see that the Until only runs for 4s.   That does not explain the 38 minute delay

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong in your "if condition". Your screenshot shows the "condition" took 0 millisecond, but it should be cancelled because of some error in the second "if condition". The run history of logic app shows 0s and misleading us.

I did a test in my side, please refer to my logic app below:
[image]
In my logic, I created a "delay" action to delay 10 minutes, then I run this logic app manually. The logic app ran the steps before the "delay" action quickly and then stayed at the "delay" action. Before 10 minutes, I use [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/cancel) to cancel this logic app, we can see it was cancelled in "Run history"(shown as below screenshot).
[image]
Then I click this item in "Run history"(I clicked it after 10 minutes, if click it before 10 minutes, the condition will show x minutes and "running" status), the "condition" shows 0s(same to yours) but not 10 minutes or longer.
[image]

According to my test, the logic app run a few minutes but the "condition" just show 0s, so I think the "condition" in your logic app also took most of the time in 38 minutes, please check the two "if condition" in your logic app. I think it should be something wrong in your second condition and it result in the cancel of your first condition.

Comment: Ok, so the hypothesis is that the action execution timing as listed cannot be trusted and may be hiding long wait times from the actions being executed in the condition?  In my logic app there is an azure function invocation at the start of the condition block so I will investigate and see if there is a differential b/w the logic app invocation and the azure function invocation

Comment: If I can confirm it, I definitely will.  Should have time to investigate today

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it **really is** suspending or idling in some way thats totally independent of the actions of the logic app??  See Update to the OP.

Comment: Hi @DaveQuinn, for this issue, I think you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). The azure support team will help you on it.

Comment: I know this is a while ago now, but I am experiencing exactly the same symptoms on one of my logic apps. @DaveQuinn, did you raise this with Microsoft and/or did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution nor file a ticket @grahama.   We just instead moved away from usage of Logic Apps as a result.